# How to adjust the volume in float value by autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, volume

Those are all function I want to do.

```
    Pause::Send {Volume_Mute}
    Insert::Send {Volume_Down 1}
    ScrollLock::Send {Volume_Up 1}
```

Press those keys to do volume controls.
Those codes seems to work, BUT I have little problem with it.
I only want it to increase/decrease 1% of volume every press.
But actually it changes 2%, it is to much to me
And it doesn't seems to work like follow codes as my expect

```
    Insert::Send {Volume_Down 0.5}
```

Have some expert know how to fix it? thank you guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically already answered this question on Super User. It is based on a library called *Vista Audio Control Functions*.
Check it out [here](https://superuser.com/a/582740/216982).

Comment: Thanks your reply, I included the va file and use the get.set func, it works well.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am a newbie to this site. I even don't know I should accept a answer and how to. now I click the check mark left of you answer.

Comment: @AeroWang Yes, you've successfully accepted my answer ;) If you find an answer especially helpful, you can even give it an upvote!

Comment: @AeroWang That's correct. You're gonna have to wait a little longer.